# Dialog.Confirm that returns boolean in Android

Tags: android, dialog, confirm

I need a Confirm dialog that returns the boolean value in order to remind the user about the missing series of values in the form that are required based on the settings but not mandatory.

I did lot of research but none of the tell me how to active this.

For example:  In a form lets say the user forgot to enter City, State and Zip.  I need to throw an reminder asking the user "Did you intentionally not enter the City?" with "Yes" and "No" buttons.  If the user answers "Yes" then throw the reminder for State else set the focus to City, so that user can enter the city. And so on....

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Vincy

Answer (score 0):

First, what you are proposing is not a particularly friendly UX. Use color coding or something to indicate fields that you think should be filled in but are not, rather than forcing the user to have to keep tapping on dialogs to do what the user wants to do.

All that being said, use `AlertDialog` (perhaps via `AlertDialog.Builder`) and set up `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` objects for the buttons. Depending upon the button choice, you either set the focus (via `requestFocus()`, called on the widget needing focus) or continue with your processing.

Comment: When there are business requirements, there is no room for user friendliness. So, i don't have choice. The suggestion you proposed is not working for me.  I need to return True or False based on user response and display the next reminder.  The example i mentioned above is just a example not the real case scenario.  The real case scenario is different for displaying the reminders.  There are like 4 reminders, one after another that needs to be displayed and captured the responses and if the user does not care then proceed with the save else stay in the form and focus to the right field.

Comment: @Vincy: "I need to return True or False based on user response and display the next reminder" -- no, you do not. Event-driven programming has been around for a couple of decades, and it is fairly important that you take the time to learn it before continuing in software development. If you wish to do something with the results of a dialog, do it in the appropriate button event handler.

Comment: lets make a deal since you're trying to be too smart.  Per your recommendation, I will take the time to learn the "Event-driven programming" but meanwhile you take the time to "understand other fellow programmers, their issue" before you open your big mouth.  If you have taken your time to read it completely and understand it you wouldn't have replied it such a way!